# How to import PapaParse with Browserify to inject into a controller?

Tags: javascript, browserify, papaparse

I'm trying to import PapaParse and use it inside a controller. This is what i tried so far:

```
import Papa from 'papaparse';
//import 'papaparse'; (tried it like this also)

angular.module('app').constant('Papa', window.Papa);
```

I think this is the right way to do it, but window.Papa is already undefined. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 16):

For me it works to import it this way in an Angular2 Component

> import * as Papa from 'papaparse';

Answer (score 1):

I just had to import papaparse before angular, now its working fine!