# How do I correctly add PapaParse to my Electron project?

Tags: javascript, electron, papaparse

I have installed it in my project folder with:

```
npm install papaparse --save
```

and included in my main.js file:

```
const Papa = require('papaparse')
```

My package.json shows papaparse as a dependancy.
However I get the following error:

```
index.html:77 Uncaught ReferenceError: Papa is not defined
    at parseStuff (index.html:77)
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (index.html:14)
```

The function:

```
function parseStuff(){
    Papa.parse('d:\\shite.csv', {
        download: true,
        complete: function(results) {
            console.log("Finished", results.data);
        }
    });
```

Only just started using Electron for a quick project (and javascript isn't my native language) so forgive me if it's something obvious.

Comment: Due to my inexperience with node or electron, I wasn't aware that I also needed to add the following to my html file, it wasn't obvious.
`var Papa = require('papaparse');`

Answer (score 0):

```
var Papa = require('papaparse');
```

The above needs to be added to the .html file.

Hopefully will help another electron newbie!

Comment: Right, you need to require the module wherever it's being used. If your function is in a `<script>` tag in your HTML file, then the `require` needs to go there. If you're not using it in your `main.js`, then you don't need to `require` there

Comment: Makes sense now, but at the time I assumed that in the `main.js` was enough, and that any `require` would be inherited.

Answer (score 0):

`import Papa from "papaparse";`

Comment: Although very short code-snippet, I would see as valid answer ... if  you please __provide an explanation__ and/or link to reference docs like: [import - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

Comment: And I doubt that this simple `import` will do for _Electron_ the same like for other web-frameworks - see similar question: [javascript - How to import PapaParse with Browserify to inject into a controller? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40439527/how-to-import-papaparse-with-browserify-to-inject-into-a-controller